# Kernel Panic: line 61: can't open /scripts/functions

Tags: 10.10, kernel

I'm facing a problem with all the kernels installed at my system (Ubuntu 10.10 64-bit).

Installed kernel versions: 2.6.32-21 up to 2.6.35.23.

The booting halted with the following error:

```
init: .: line 61: can't open '/scripts/functions'
Kernel panic - not syncing: Attempted to kill init!
Pid: 1, comm: init not tainted
```

Only the first one (2.6.32-21) was working up until know.

I asked for help at [ubuntuforums.org](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1630528) and i was told to check if there's any problem regarding my graphics card (ATI Radeon).

I uninstalled all the ATI-related packages as well as all the unecessary xserver-xorg-video-* drivers that were installed.

I then rebooted and from then on ALL of the kernels halt with the same error (i.e. it didn't fix the problematic kernels, it just broke the only one that was working...)

Any ideas on what i should try next?

Thanks in advance.

Pavlos.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem Solved!
To anyone interested, here's my solution:
It was update-initramsfs which caused the above errors (invalid predicate -regextype' find: invalid predicate -regextype').
The created initrd images were broken.
Something was wrong with **findutils**, so I just reinstalled the package (as well as **initramfs-tools**) and the problem's gone :-)
Thanks once again for helping out.

Comment: Had this problem on a server. I also needed to change the attributes on find to be able to reinstall findutils: `chattr -i /usr/bin/find` and `chattr -a /usr/bin/find`.

Answer (score 1):

1. Boot using cd
2. Mount existing ubuntu
3. chroot to existing ubuntu
4. `apt-get install --reinstall findutils`
5. `update-initramfs -u`

This worked for me

Answer (score 0):

I had, ones in a life time Kernel Panic... and it was scary :)
The problem was related to a hardware failure. In my occasion, it was a newly purchased RAM module. The first time I installed the module, system was booting normally, but suddenly it started to give me kernel panic. What I did, was to check my RAM.

In the GRUB menu there is a an entry for Memtest-86+. Try it, to see if something is wrong with your RAM. Be patient though, it may take some time to give some results...

**UPDATE** You can use Live CD and then from the menu choose
Test memory

[image]

Comment: I'll let Memtest scan for possible defects as you said and i'll let you know if it finds anything.

Answer (score 0):

Try booting into recovery mode. If that works, run `sudo update-initramfs`, reboot. See if you can boot into the normal mode.

If recovery mode is not working, I think the only viable way would be to reinstall (back up all your files from `/home` somewhere, reinstall, copy them back - use a LiveCD for that).

Comment: Thank you both for answering. 
@Salih: I guess that if there was a problem with RAM, then i wouldn't be able to boot with any kernel from the start. Isn't that right?
@evgeny: Recovery mode is also not working. I'm currently stuck at chrooting and trying to reinstall multiple kernel versions, but still nothings seems to work..

Comment: Update: i forgot to tell you that update-initramfs is always giving me the following warnings (for every kernel):

find: invalid predicate `-regextype'
find: invalid predicate `-regextype'
find: warning: unrecognized format directive `%Y'

Comment: I daresay your system broke. Like, entirely. A clean reinstall might save you time than trying to fix everything.

Comment: I daresay i have to agree with you :-)
But as a technician, i'm always interested to know what the exact problem is, and that's not gonna happen if i just reinstall.
Anyways, thanks for the feedback, i'll give it another shot tomorrow and if nothing happens, i guess i'll go on with the reinstallation...